# how to deploy react to heroku

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im having trouble deploying this simple react app. It works perfect on my localhost. Im thinking of an unresolved cors problem but didnt found much information bout it

the error i get:

```
    at j (Nav.js:9)
    at ro (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Bo (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
    at Wi (react-dom.production.min.js:269)
    at Pu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at xu (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at vu (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
```

Here's where I make my axios.get from the endpoint -> http://179.43.113.170:8082/test/ta/sistema_solar.json

```
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Header from "./Header";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Gallery from "./Gallery";

const App = () => {
console.log("APP LOADED!");
const [planetas, setPlanetas] = useState([]);
const getPlanetas = () => {
 axios.get("/test/ta/sistema_solar.json").then((response) => {
   setPlanetas(response.data);
   console.log(response.data);
 });
};
useEffect(() => {
 getPlanetas();
}, []);
return (
 <div className="maindiv">
   <Header />
   <Nav planetas={planetas} />
   <Gallery planetas={planetas} />
 </div>
);
};

export default App;
```

I also use a proxy configuration on my packege.json

"proxy": "http://179.43.113.170:8082"

Comment: did u create a node server?

Comment: The server providing the JSON is online, I have made previous react proyects where I can get the data from endpoint witouth problems... any idea ?

Comment: in order to deploy a react app on heroku, you have to create a node.js server will serve the react project. then you have to deploy the node server

Answer (score 0):

You should make an node js (express) server to serve your react app's production files and deploy your server and files to heroku . Heroku only uses node js server to serve anything .

Comment: The server providing the JSON is online, I have made previous react proyects where I can get the data from endpoint witouth problems... any idea ?